# Excel form to read/write from linked .xlsx

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016, forms

I've inherited a partially complete project where a student developer is using excel as a database.

Hes tried to separate the user interface (created with excel forms) and the "database" which is a worksheet in a separate excel workbook. (As i would do with access and linked tables.)

I suspect the form was in the same work book and has been moved into a separate workbook. It can read data but isnt writing back.

Is this a feasible or common approach?   Can anyone share a simple working example of a vba form that can open/read from and write to a remote spreadsheet?

Comment: No, it's not a common approach to separate forms and data in Excel, anyway Excel probably isn't the right tool for that. "Can anyone share a simple working example of a vba form" - that's off-topic here, this site is not about sharing code / templates but answering specific questions

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks for you reply. I take your points. Even if its not common, is it feasible? A bad idea is one thing. Impossible/doomed to fail is another.

Comment: Without knowing your problem in details and your expertise with macros is difficult to estimate how bad idea it is. Just suppose you need to improve your file time to time, sometimes it also crashes, how bad is for you to come back here to ask for help and wait a few days until you receive it?